# Step ‘Deploy war/ear to a container’ aborted due to exception failed to copy to container

Tags: maven, jenkins

I getting below error while copying the war to tomcat server

```
[INFO] Replacing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/war-deploy-tomcat/target/TC-maven-0.1.0.jar with /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/war-deploy-tomcat/target/TC-maven-0.1.0-shaded.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.722 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-06T06:32:19Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/war-deploy-tomcat/pom.xml to www.techiescorner.in/TC-maven/0.1.0/TC-maven-0.1.0.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/war-deploy-tomcat/target/TC-maven-0.1.0.jar to www.techiescorner.in/TC-maven/0.1.0/TC-maven-0.1.0.jar
channel stopped
ERROR: Step ‘Deploy war/ear to a container’ aborted due to exception: 
java.lang.InterruptedException: [DeployPublisher][WARN] No wars found. Deploy aborted. %n
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:107)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1074)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

1. I have confirmed I could connect to tomcat server from my jenkins
       the server on port 8080.

   2. Confirmed tomcat user has the right permission    ()
   3. Project configuration details.
      [image]
      [image]
   4. Code is in github https://github.com/techiescorner/sample-maven-project.git
   5. I could see tar file is generated under Jenkins workspace target folder.
   6. Confirmed github and maven plugin are installed.

Answer (score 1):

check pom file.. if you use

finalName> Name </finalName  Tag**--

war file created only in this tag name..  you need to use that name only(*.war)

Answer (score 1):

you might be missing the format of this configuration `**/*.war`:

1. Do not use space between `*` and `.war`
2. [image]

Answer (score 0):

check the user you have created in /usr/share/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml 
if you put the correct username and password or not 
and if you did and still not working check if your  and  are not a comment if you find  --> that means it's a comment and you tomcat can't detect that user

Answer (score 0):

Your output file is .jar format. In order to deploy it to the web application you need to build it as a .war file. You can change your pom.xml file to build as .war. It should look like something like this.

```
<groupId>com.sarav</groupId>
<artifactId>TomcatMavenApp</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that, Child of **project** tag, I need to add **packaging** tag with value war. You can add below the **version** tag.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```